# Why doesn't purrr::transpose work with the pipe operator?

Tags: r, purrr, magrittr

I don't understand why `purrr::transpose` issues an error after the pipe operator.
This isn"t the case with other functions like `purrr::map`.

See example below:

```
library(purrr)
# Works
identical(mtcars %>% map(~{.x}), mtcars %>% purrr::map(~{.x}))
# [1] TRUE

# Works
mtcars %>% transpose

# Doesn't work
mtcars %>% purrr::transpose
#Error in .::purrr : unused argument (transpose)
```

Comment: You need `mtcars %>% purrr::transpose(.)` to invoke the function

Comment: Thanks @Akrun. But why don't I need `tranpose(.)`?

Comment: It is equivalent to calling `mtcars %>% `::`(purrr, transpose)`  So you need to wrap with `()` i.e `mtcars %>% (`::`(purrr, transpose))`

Comment: @akrun There is an issue in the formatting of  your previous comment for backticks arround the namespace operator in the inline code block.This is an important  to revealing what the operator is and so the character needs to be escaped if possible.

Comment: I did backquote, but it didn't show because of the backquote at the end

Comment: @akrun I could see that you had I was worried from a readers perspective. I don't know if the characters can be escaped or made visible. I was having the same problem displaying them using the inline code blocks.

Comment: @JoelKandiah There is a way to show it, but I don't remember it

Comment: No worries then. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible I have misunderstood the namespace operator please correct me if so however this is what I believe the reason to be.

I believe this is an issue where the namespace notation actually acts as an infix operator `::`. This means that the function call it is trying to use is:

```r
`::`(mtcars, purrr, transpose)
```

The error here occurs as the namespace infix operator can only accept two arguments: the package name and the function from the package.

This isn't expected by the user as we would want to be able to use functions from external namespaces with the pipe operator. This is because the code is confused as to what the function attempting to be called is and so it finds the first function it can (in this case `::`).

The solution to this is to use brackets to note that `transpose` is the function or that `purrr::transpose` should be evaluated first. We can do this with the following code:

```r
# purrr::transpose is the function
mtcars %>% purrr::transpose()

# Evaluate this block as the expression of the function
mtcars %>% (purrr::transpose)
```

Comment: Thanks @Joel, this gives me a direction to look for, I'll give you feedback as soon as I have tested further.

Comment: I see what you mean, but do you see a reason why `map` should behave differently than `transpose` (see the examples I gave)?

Comment: Hey I briefly touched on this in the description as the map call has the brackets at the end in your example it knows the whole expression is the function. If you'd like you can check that you get the same error if you try any namespace::function rather than namespace::function()